# Rfid is not working

Tags: arduino-uno

I am making a rfid card cognition code to find out what id does my card have.

I used rfid-rc522 module. And I set the pins like this picture.

[image: rfid]

I'm using a genuine Arduino uno. and my code is this:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <MFRC522.h>

#define RST_PIN   9                            // reset핀은 9번으로 설정
#define SS_PIN    10                           // SS핀은 10번으로 설정
                                               // SS핀은 데이터를 주고받는 역할의 핀( SS = Slave Selector )

MFRC522 mfrc(SS_PIN, RST_PIN);                 // MFR522를 이용하기 위해 mfrc객체를 생성해 줍니다.

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);                         // 시리얼 통신, 속도는 9600
  SPI.begin();                                // SPI 초기화
                                              // (SPI : 하나의 마스터와 다수의 SLAVE(종속적인 역활)간의 통신 방식)
  mfrc.PCD_Init();                               
}

void loop(){
  if ( !mfrc.PICC_IsNewCardPresent() || !mfrc.PICC_ReadCardSerial() ) {   
                                               // 태그 접촉이 되지 않았을때 또는 ID가 읽혀지지 않았을때
    delay(500);                                // 0.5초 딜레이 
    return;                                    // return
  } 

  Serial.print("Card UID:");                  // 태그의 ID출력

  for (byte i = 0; i < 4; i++) {               // 태그의 ID출력하는 반복문.태그의 ID사이즈(4)까지
    Serial.print(mfrc.uid.uidByte[i]);        // mfrc.uid.uidByte[0] ~ mfrc.uid.uidByte[3]까지 출력
    Serial.print(" ");                        // id 사이의 간격 출력
  }
  Serial.println(); 
}
```

And I used library [rfid-master](https://github.com/miguelbalboa/rfid) which is in the github

So, when I try to get the card to the reader [see video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QuTxDe3MkwhXv0W6KtwHEGNvGvrB-P74/view?usp=sharing), it doesn't work like the video. What is the problem?

Comment: You have to explain in what way it doesn't work like the video.

Comment: Can you read the key fob using the DumpInfo.ino sketch that came with the library?

Comment: This would be a good question if you explained a little more on what you expect to happen and what exactly isn't working.